# Firebase API is not called from Android unit test

Tags: android, firebase, junit, firebase-realtime-database, junit4

This unit test is not hitting the Firebase server. If the same unit test is run using a breakpoint, it will hit the server. This leads me to believe it may be related to the thread that Firebase is using for background work.

I tried running the code on the UI thread, but there was no change. I have also tried using the instrumentation context when getting the Firebase instance.

Why does this code only work when using a breakpoint?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class FirebaseTest : AndroidJUnitRunner() {    
    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun doTheTest() {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("test").push()
        assertTrue(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#push()) itself doesn't do anything on the server, so I don't think you would ever see a change if all you executed was that one line of code.  push() just generates a key value (based on the current time) and constructs a DatabaseReference that points to that key.  Nothing is written until you write something to the DatabaseReference, like this:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("test").push()
ref.setValue(...)
```

That will asynchronously write the value you give to that location at the key generated by push(), and you can't expect that it will have completed the transaction by the end of the test, unless you block the test until it verifies that completed the round trip.

Comment: It looks like your answer also related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535740/difference-between-firebase-instance-and-databasereference). Can you answer it? Because I'm also curious. :)